# Hibernate: Issues with running update query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I see there are two ways to create `update query` in Hibernate. First you can go with the standard approach where we have hql like:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("update" + LogsBean.class.getName() + " LogsBean " + "set LogsBean.jobId= :jobId where LogsBean.jobId= :oldValue ");
            q.setLong("jobId", jobId);
            q.setLong("oldValue", 0);
            return q.executeUpdate();
```

or we can go and run

```
getHibernateTemplate.saveorupdate(jobId);
```

Now am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!` on running first query and am not sure hwo to provide condition in `getHibernateTemplate` example, i want to update `jobIds` in log table whose value matches 0 and so i want to run something like

```
Update logs set jobId = 23 where jobId = 0
```

Above is the simple `sql` query that I am trying to run but I want to run this via hibernate, tried couple ways but it is not working, any suggestions?

**Update:**

As noted by Jeff, issue was not having space after update and so that issue got resolved but still values are not updated, i have updated show_sql true for hibernate and checking what could be the cause of the issue, will be running query generated by hibernate to run again db and see if records are updated.

Comment: Maybe using a `createNativeQuery` instead of createQuery.

Comment: you don't have a space between update and LogsBean.class.getName().  Is that just a typo when you wrote the question or in the actual code?

Comment: In the first query provided, there is no space after the keyword 'update'. Is that the issue?.

Comment: @jeff: you nailed it perfectly...let me test it and will update :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few things that might help you to resolve this:

- What does [`.executeUpdate()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29) return, 0 (as it did not update any
  rows)?
- Does it throw a [`HibernateException`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html) that you are
  silently catching or rethrowing?
- Which [`FlushMode`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html) do you have configured?
- Does the update get to the DB? You could switch on the query log for your DB server.